# Generate a XML Version File automatically with Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#

I am using the [Autoupdater.NET package](https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET/blob/master/README.md) in a C# project of mine.

The package uses an XML file stored on (my) server to check if there is a new version of my software available, now it would be a nice thing to autogenerate this XML file everytime I build a new version of my code.

So, after each new build, there should be a file "myProject_1.4.2.xml" in the project folder.

How can I build a "tool" or some kind of plugin for Visual Studio (2019) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Build Events for this.
In VS, go to Project Properties -> Build Events.
In the Post-build event command line area you can execute something to create the XML for you.